# getting Vim directory for vimrc file

Tags: vim

How do I get the directory Vim is 'looking into'? I want to set up my `vimrc` platform independent so I don't want to put explicit directories. On Linux e.g. vim looks into `~/.vim` and on Windows in `~\vimfiles`. How can I get the directory that is used, to put my files there?

Comment: The answer is more complicated than you seem to expect.  There are several relevant directories, and some of them are hardcoded.  See `:h startup` for details.  See also the output of `vim --version`.

Comment: Where do you need the vim folder in your `.vimrc`? I just checked my `.vimrc`, and the only place I'm using it, is for temporary files. Can you elaborate a bit what the use case is?

Comment: First is the also the temporary files. I save `undo` and `backup` files in subdirectories of `.vim`. The other things are my plug-ins. I use 'vim-plug` and need to specify the folder.
I want to keep this all in one folder that I can just put my `.vim` folder on GitHub and sync it, also to systems not having Git installed.

Comment: You could check and see if you are on a windows machine add *.vim* folder to *runtimepath* : `if has('win32') || has('win64') | set rtp+=$HOME/.vim | endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say this is an information we never need as I have one use for it.

In lh-vim-lib, I proceed this way (in [lh#path#vimfiles()](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/path.vim#L525)):

- First I build a regex from $HOME (i.e. I replace all slashes and backslahes into `[/\\]`): `:let regex = substitute($HOME, '[/\\]', '[/\\\\]', 'g')`.
- Then I append the possible directories: `let regex .= '\(vimfiles\|.vim\)'`
- And i finally, I search for my regex into &rtp. The shortest result is the good one. `:let paths = filter(split(&rtp, ','), 'match(v:val, regex) != -1')` + `:return paths[lh#list#arg_min(paths, function('len'))]`

Note: The real code is a little bit more complex, generic and resilient (/resistant?)  to errors.

PS: because of cygwin, testing for `has('win32')` is not enough.

EDIT: I've been asked to provide [`lh#list#arg_min()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/list.vim#L430) definition. It can be found in lh-vim-lib. Its definition is quite simple and a little bit cumbersome (IMO)

```
function! lh#list#arg_min(list, ...) abort
  if empty(a:list) | return -1 | endif
  let Transfo = a:0 > 0 ? a:1 : function(s:getSNR(id))
  let m = Transfo(a:list[0])
  let p = 0
  let i = 1
  while i != len(a:list)
    let e = a:list[i]
    let v = Transfo(e)
    if v < m
      let m = v
      let p = i
    endif
    let i += 1
  endwhile
  return p
endfunction
```

Comment: There is a bracket too much after `&rtp` (I can't edit it, apparently I would have to change more characters). Can you maybe also give the definition of `lh#list#arg_min`, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Indeed thanks. I've made the correction. Regarding `arg_min`, it's not that complex, but still a little bit cumbersome. It's definition is available here: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/list.vim#L430

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default `'runtimepath'` to make Vim use the same `~/.vim/` on Windows, too. Just put this into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
if has('win32') || has('win64')
    let &runtimepath = substitute(&runtimepath, '\C\V' . escape($HOME.'/vimfiles', '\'), escape($HOME.'/.vim', '\&'), 'g')
endif
```